# Count how many UL have so many LI elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have various **UL** and I need to know about all existing **UL**, how many **UL** have two **LI**, what I'm trying to do with a each, this will be the right way.

```js
$(function(){

 var count = '';
 var total = 1;
    
 $('ul li').each(function(index, el) {
   count++;
   if(count == 12) {
    total + 1;
   }
      
   count = '';
  });
    
    console.log('We found 2 UL with 2 li');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

The this code, result: We found 2 UL with 2 li.

Comment: `total + 1` doesn't do anything. It should be `total++`. And why are you doing `count++` when `count` is a string, not a number?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {


  $('ul').filter(function() {

    return $(this).children('li').length == 2
  }).css("background-color", "red")

  console.log('We found 2 UL with 2 li');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

You can use filter then return the ul with li length == 2

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very quick response, you have a great day.

Comment: @Learningandsharing glad to help mate happy coding

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var count = 0;
  $('ul').each(function(index, item) {
  if($(this).children('li').length == 2)
  {
  count++;
  }
  });
  
  if(count > 0)
  {
  console.log('We found '+ count +' UL with 2 li');
  }
  else
  {
  console.log('no such li is found')
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very quick response, you have a great day.